# remove displayed url in the bottom of browser on mousehover of jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove the url displayed at the bottom of the browser when mouse hover/clicked is done on the jquery tabs.

Refer url below:

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/vertical.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the status bar is showing the URL of the tab link is because that link has received focus. Of course, clicking away will remove the focus and clear your status bar, but to make sure it doesn't do that at all you can do a few things:

1. Make the clickable element ***not*** a link. Links are focusable. Use a `div` or a `span`. (Drawbacks: for accessibility, you *want* tab elements to be focusable - ie, have a `tabindex`)
2. Remove the `href` value of the `<a>` tag. You could use something like `<a data-href="#tab1">` instead (though that would require rewriting the jQueryUI code thus negating its benefit).
3. What I'd recommend is just adding a `.blur()` (the opposite of `.focus()`) on the element after it is clicked, or `.focus()`ing on something else. Looking at jQueryUI's demo, I'd say it's most appropriate to give focus to the content displayed (great for screenreaders)

Something like:

```
$('.ui-tabs-anchor').click(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).href()).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, to hide the URL from the status bar of browser.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='Put your link here'">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Just to help, remember that if you do your navigation on this way, you will not be able to use the "Open link in ..." options from the browser (mouse 3 click, etc)

Comment: Do you mean on clicking the link a blank page is displayed?

Comment: no when the page is loaded it displays the blank page,Can you please post a fiddle applying this on jquery tabs